# How to monitor "Sum" in order to estimate the time of "Sum"?

Tags: summation

I am dealing with a `Sum` on a large scale, which can not run out an answer on my computer. I want to know if there is some command that allow me to monitor the process of `Sum`,for example print during the `Sum`, then I could estimate the time of it. Thanks for any advice!

*I have tried the `FullSimplify` but it failed to give an expression.

```
ClearAll[xm, b, n`value, A`value, L`value, ans`vt, ans`vs, tem, \
answer, F, F1, F2]

(*Setting*)
xm = 2750;
b = 18782/10000;
F[x_] := 1 - (xm/x)^b;

n`value = 880000;
A`value = 3000;
L`value = 3000;

tem = ((n`value - j) + 
     A`value (2*L`value + A`value))/(n`value*(A`value + L`value));
ans`vt = 55210;
ans`vs = 55408;

F1 = N[F[ans`vt], 20];
F2 = N[F[ans`vs], 20];

(*Calculation*)
answer = N[
   Sum[Binomial[n`value, j]*F1^(n`value - j)*(1 - F1)^j*tem*
     Sum[Binomial[j, i]*F2^(j - i)*(1 - F2)^i, {i, 0, A`value}], {j, 
     A`value + 1, n`value - L`value - 1}], 20] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Use e.g.: `answer= Monitor[ N[Sum[....]],  j ]`

Comment: *I have tried the FullSimplify but it failed to give an expression.* You’re calculating a number. How would FullSimplify help?

Comment: @Ghoster If the FullSimplify gives an expression, then it shorten the time I cost to get the number.

Comment: By the way, for speeding the calcultion of this problem, I later find out that`Binomial[n·value, j]*F1^(n·value - j)*(1 - F1)^j` goes to 0 as `j` goes high like 4000, so we could speed it just by replace `n·value - L·value - 1` to 4000.